# Connecting Azure Site-to-Site VPN to On-prem Gateway with 2 public IP's

Tags: azure, cisco, site-to-site-vpn, azure-networking, cisco-vpn

I have a cisco ISR on-prem with 2 endpoints (primary and secondary) and I want to connect my Azure VPN Gateway to both endpoints through a single connection (same local address space for both IP's).

When creating an Azure *local network gateway* I can only enter 1 public IP address, not 2.
Is there a way to connect with 2 IP's from the Azure VPN Gateway?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done the way you are asking.  You have a couple options.  You can set up both onprem Devices to the same VPN Gateway.

[image: Multiple on-premises VPN devices]

Or, you can set up a full mesh.

[image: Active-active VPN gateways]

More details here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-highlyavailable#multiple-on-premises-vpn-devices

Comment: Thanks, I see that both options require BGP, but do both options also require a redundant Azure VPN setup (either active active or active/standy) or can a single instance work as well?

Comment: No, the first option doesn't require you to create a second VPN gateway.  It is showing the default secondary VPN created by the service.  Every Azure VPN gateway consists of two instances in an active-standby configuration.  BC of this config, there is a brief outage as the active swap occurs.  The Active-Active config can remove that swap over outage.